# How to restrict laravel route for all users and can be accessed only by the app

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, routes

is there any way where i can make the route so that no use can navigate nor can use that route and only the app can send request to that route for example using ajax. Is there any way?

Comment: You want to restrict it with some ip address? I mean, how to define your app?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? If the app can send a request then any user can also send a request.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict it so taht only my server can access the routes? i mean send requests?

Comment: Well if your server has a fixed IP address then maybe yes